# Uninstalling chrome extension and associated localStorage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am testing a chrome extension in dev mode. Once I finish it, I packaged it and installed on my machine! It is working. But I am not sure whether the old localStorage was removed when I uninstalled the extension from browser(Dev mode).

Will the associated localStorage be removed when uninstalling an extension from dev mode and installing the same thing as a packaged extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All associated data with an extension is removed when the extension is uninstalled. You can verify this by visiting your Chrome profile directory, and descend in `Local Storage`. You'll see a SQLLite database (eg. `chrome-extension_lndfmdleiloedhcbmjofibnflfbjhpha_0.localstorage`).

After removing the extension, this database disappears.